# System overlay affecting key guard

Tags: java, android, overlay, keyguard

I can't seem to fix this weird keyguard problem.

### Symptoms:

When I have a system overlay added, my keyguard is blank. I can however push buttons (PIN Lock and emergency call, etc) and even unlock my phone (thank god!).

### Code:

#### Java

```
    viewHUD = new CustomView(getApplicationContext());

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(viewHUD, params);
```

### Screenshots

#### 1.Keyguard Open (what it usually looks like)

[image: Keyguard Open]

#### 2.Buggy keyguard i.e. When I run this overlay app and press the power button twice (for the lock to engage)

[image: Buggy keyguard]

#### 3. App Screen (Notice the Cyan text `-- mA`)

[image: App Screen]

#### 4. Keyguard close/minimized

[image: Keyguard close/minimized]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, and I've found a solution, here it goes, this fixes the problem:

```
    viewToAdd.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    // make the required params object for the HUD viewToAdd
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
```